# How to get json data from google spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I am trying to get JSON data from publicly shared Google SpreadSheets that are created by from other users.

To call that api I use the following url format: `https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/[sheet_id]/[tab_id]/public/basic?alt=json`

But when I set the `sheet_id` from the one I get from a shared link I receive 404 response. :-(

[image]

By the way, I can get JSON data from same shared link if I make it public on the web.

Like this:

[image]

Can I get json data from only another users shared link?

This is my application condition.

1. Shared link can be sent from many people.
2. Those links are not public to the web.
3. I make sheet_id from shared link and call api.
4. I run application from api response data.

Thank you for your patience and please excuse my poor English.

Comment: Can you share an example shared link and the full HTTP request you're making?

Comment: this may give you some direction https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30082277/accessing-a-new-style-public-google-sheet-as-json, I think to get a private sheet data you need authentication.

Comment: @smarx Thank you! This is sample url! https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TlGL9JASdAidux2xAMKKbWOeMEAJswzRUdp4cWqnDzg/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what API method you're using, but this seems to work fine on the example spreadsheet you gave. (Make sure to include your API key.)

```
GET https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1TlGL9JASdAidux2xAMKKbWOeMEAJswzRUdp4cWqnDzg/values/texts?key=<REDACTED>
```