# How do I move a client side script call over to the server? (Google Drive Spreadsheet Feed)

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I'm working with Google drive sheets and using them as a simple data store.  Google makes it very friendly to obtain a feed from a public sheet via a *client* side script call in the *browser*.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function useJSONdata(root) {
        var feed = root.feed;
        var entries = feed.entry || [];
        var html = [''];
        for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
            var entry = entries[i];
            (process the data, etc...)
        }
    }
</script>

<body>
    <script src='https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/od6/public/full?alt=json-in-script&callback=useJSONdata'></script>
</body>
```

There is a lot of info available on this technique.  [Old technique here](https://developers.google.com/gdata/samples/spreadsheet_sample), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30082277/accessing-a-new-style-public-google-sheet-as-json).  Here's a link to a [handy flash card tool I wrote](http://dogfeatherdesign.com/Extras/flashcards.html), code all visible in your browser's dev tools.

But in my current use case, I'd like access to the Google spreadsheet data from node.js in the *server*.  I'm not seeing the best translation of `<script src='https://...&callback=...'></script>` from document client code to valid server code.

I've been attempting to make this work using https requests, both GET and POST.  I can see that those requests are obtaining data, but the returned data is bizzare.  I'm looking at 7000 lines of returned info on a spreadsheet with ten lines of content.

here is a curl command to look at my test spreadsheet data:
`curl https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1s9-AyqYqp25s2OeGiglCSNF2UcvJJm50Ipvm8v0Mgo0/od6/public/full?alt=json-in-script`

Data returned from a browser `<script src=...` request:

```
encoding:"UTF-8"
feed:
    author:[{…}]
    category:[{…}]
    entry:(167) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, …]
    id:{$t: "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/xxxxxxxx/od6/public/full"}
    link:(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
    openSearch$startIndex:{$t: "1"}
    openSearch$totalResults:{$t: "167"}
    title:{type: "text", $t: "Sheet1"}
    updated:{$t: "2015-04-04T19:31:32.089Z"}
    xmlns:"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns$gsx:"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006/extended"
    xmlns$openSearch:"http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/"
__proto__:Object
```

I've been looking at the returned data from my node.js https GET server request (via [chrome debugger tools](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xb_0awoShR8)) and that data is unusable.  A POST request nets me a statusCode 405 error.

```
response: IncomingMessage
    client:TLSSocket {_tlsOptions: {…}, _secureEstablished: true, _securePending: false, _newSessionPending: false, _controlReleased: true, …}
    complete:false
    connection:TLSSocket {_tlsOptions: {…}, _secureEstablished: true, _securePending: false, _newSessionPending: false, _controlReleased: true, …}
    domain:null
    headers:{content-type: "application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8", x-robots-tag: "noindex, nofollow, nosnippet", expires: "Wed, 27 Dec 2017 02:50:15 GMT", date: "Wed, 27 Dec 2017 02:50:15 GMT", cache-control: "private, max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-transform", …}
    httpVersion:"1.1"
    httpVersionMajor:1
    httpVersionMinor:1
    method:null
    rawHeaders:(38) ["Content-Type", "application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8", "X-Robots-Tag", "noindex, nofollow, nosnippet", "Expires", "Wed, 27 Dec 2017 02:50:15 GMT", "Date", "Wed, 27 Dec 2017 02:50:15 GMT", "Cache-Control", "private, max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-transform", "Vary", "Accept, X-GData-Authorization, GData-Version", "GData-Version", "1.0", "Last-Modified", "Tue, 26 Dec 2017 20:36:41 GMT", "Transfer-Encoding", "chunked", "P3P", "CP="This is not a P3P policy! See g.co/p3phelp for more info."", "P3P", "CP="This is not a P3P policy! See g.co/p3phelp for more info."", "X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff", "X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN", "X-XSS-Protection", "1; mode=block", "Server", "GSE", "Set-Cookie", "NID=120=CFx_iglHazKNNR7tH33m4UkGABss7TV9bB03EVnZrH…=/;Expires=Thu, 28-Jun-2018 02:50:15 GMT;HttpOnly", "Set-Cookie", "NID=120=W3n0zQ1UWJz6pmTOjKjAxuMtG5WOLx2D3OiQca5R9A…=/;Expires=Thu, 28-Jun-2018 02:50:15 GMT;HttpOnly", "Alt-Svc", "hq=":443"; ma=2592000; quic=51303431; quic=5130333…03335,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="41,39,38,37,35"", "Connection", "close"]
    rawTrailers:[]
    read:ƒ (n)
    readable:true
    req:ClientRequest {domain: null, _events: {…}, _eventsCount: 2, _maxListeners: undefined, output: Array(0), …}
    socket:TLSSocket {_tlsOptions: {…}, _secureEstablished: true, _securePending: false, _newSessionPending: false, _controlReleased: true, …}
    statusCode:200
    statusMessage:"OK"
    trailers:{}
    upgrade:false
    url:""
    _consuming:true
    _dumped:false
    _events:{end: ƒ, data: ƒ}
    _eventsCount:2
    _maxListeners:undefined
    _readableState:ReadableState {objectMode: false, highWaterMark: 16384, buffer: BufferList, length: 0, pipes: null, …}
    destroyed:(...)
    readableHighWaterMark:(...)
    __proto__:Readable
```

Is there a better way to convert that `<script src=...` code to a server request for data from a Google Drive Spreadsheet??  Anybody been here before?

Comment: There's a whole node.js library for Google Sheets that you could look in to: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs

Comment: @ChrisRiebschlager  Obviously you are correct, that is the best way forward.  The new Google Sheets API (ver 4) uses OAuth permissions, something not required for previous simple feeds.  I will utilize that for new projects going forward, but I intend to answer my own question for previous API version feeds.  thx for the link.

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to figure this one out. I ended up using the 'request' tool, in lieu of an HTTPS format.

```
var request = require('request');
request.get(
    'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1s9-AyqYqp25s2OeGiglCSNF2UcvJJm50Ipvm8v0Mgo0/od6/public/full?alt=json',
    function(error, response, body) {
        console.log('error: ', error); // print the error if one occurred.
        console.log('statusCode: ', response && response.statusCode, "\n\n\n"); // Print the response status code if a response was received
        console.log("response.body: ", response.body, "\n\n\n");
    }
}
```

This worked easily enough.  There was one trick, the use of `?alt=json` in the feed address.

Do note, this technique seems to be superseded with [version 4 of the Google Sheets Api,](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs) which now includes OAuth tokens / credentials.  The use of that API makes sense for all new work going forward.