# Google sheets unable to parse range

Tags: google-sheets-api

I am posting the following (incomplete code) to Google sheets batch update values:

`{"valueInputOption":"USER_ENTERED","data":[{"range":"'Home Sheet'!B2:B2","values":[`

And for some reason I am getting:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid data[0]: Unable to parse range: 'Home Sheet'!B2:B2",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

However if you refer to https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts this clearly looks like the range is valid. Interestingly this is only in the Javascript not if I use the PHP sdk.

Comment: What if you edit that to `'Home Sheet'!B2`?

Comment: Wierdly I had tried that prior to this but unfortunately still no good

Comment: `INVALID_ARGUMENT` means the sheet or range cannot be found. Test with another sheet: "Sheet1!A1" or another file.

Comment: The sheet definitely exists ...

Comment: And what do you get from the API when you query `spreadsheets#get` for the sheet names? e.g. https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/sheets/v4/sheets.spreadsheets.get?spreadsheetId=yourSpreadsheetId&fields=sheets%252Fproperties%252Ftitle

Answer (score 3):

When accessing a public sheet via URL like this:

```
https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetID}/values/{sheetName}?key={API Key}
```

I have to replace the space in the sheet name with %20, or remove the space from the sheet name if possible. Like this:

```
https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetID}/values/Home%20Sheet!B2:B2?key={API Key}
```

So this works for me so long as the sheet sharing is set to "Anyone with the link can view."

[See this answer for more detailed info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44479726/588390).

Comment: Most client libraries (Google's, at least) will automatically URL-encode querystring / URL parameters, such as spaces to `%20`.