# Google Sheets v4 Update Effect JSON Endpoint Data? Shut down on June 8, 2021

Tags: javascript, php, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

[image]

I read this [article](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/v3) about a Google Sheet API v4 update. Do I need to change the current code structure?

I am using [simple JSON data](https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1l7VfPOI3TYtPuBZlZ-JMMiZW1OK6rzIBt8RFd6KmwbA/1/public/values?alt=json) for displaying Google sheet data on the web. I made some PHP and JavaScript base project on the web, using the below code below:

```
.HTML
 var sf = https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1l7VfPOI3TYtPuBZlZ-JMMiZW1OK6rzIBt8RFd6KmwbA/1/public/values?alt=json

 $.getJSON(sf, function(data) {
 var sd = data.feed.entry;

 key = data.feed.entry[i]['gsx$key']['$t'];
 name = data.feed.entry[i]['gsx$name']['$t'];
 img = data.feed.entry[i]['gsx$img']['$t'];
 rice = data.feed.entry[i]['gsx$price']['$t'];
```

```
.php

$url = 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1l7VfPOI3TYtPuBZlZ-JMMiZW1OK6rzIBt8RFd6KmwbA/1/public/values?alt=json';
$file = file_get_contents($url); 
$json = json_decode($file);

$rows = $json->{'feed'}->{'entry'};

$key = $row->{'gsx$key'}->{'$t'};
$price = $row->{'gsx$price'}->{'$t'};
$img = $row->{'gsx$img'}->{'$t'};
$name = $row->{'gsx$name'}->{'$t'};
```

Do I really need to update anything?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to change the endpoint from Sheets API v3 to others.

#### Issue and workaround:

At Sheets API v3, this API could be used without the access token and API key. But in the case of Sheets API v4, the access token and/or API key are required to be used. It seems that this is the current specification. When I saw your script, the access token and API key are not used. So in this answer, as a workaround, I would like to propose the method for retrieving the values from the Spreadsheet without the access token and API key. The endpoint is as follows.

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{spreadsheetId}/gviz/tq
```

This is the endpoint used with the Query Language. As an important point, in this case, the Google Spreadsheet is required to publish as the Web publish. Please be careful this. When I saw the URL of your Spreadsheet, it seems that the Spreadsheet is published as the Web publish. So your Spreadsheet can be used with the following script.

In this answer, the script of Javascript is used.

#### Sample script 1:

In this sample script, the values of Spreadsheet are directly retrieved as the CSV data.

```
var sf = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1l7VfPOI3TYtPuBZlZ-JMMiZW1OK6rzIBt8RFd6KmwbA/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv";
$.ajax({url: sf, type: 'GET', dataType: 'text'})
.done(function(csv) {
  console.log(csv);
})
.fail((e) => console.log(e.status));
```

#### Sample script 2:

In this sample script, the values of Spreadsheet are retrieved as JSON data, and parsed it as the header row and values.

```
var sf = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1l7VfPOI3TYtPuBZlZ-JMMiZW1OK6rzIBt8RFd6KmwbA/gviz/tq?tqx=out:json";
$.ajax({url: sf, type: 'GET', dataType: 'text'})
.done(function(data) {
  const r = data.match(/google\.visualization\.Query\.setResponse\(([\s\S\w]+)\)/);
  if (r && r.length == 2) {
    const obj = JSON.parse(r[1]);
    const table = obj.table;
    const header = table.cols.map(({label}) => label);
    const rows = table.rows.map(({c}) => c.map(e => e ? (e.v || "") : "")); // Modified from const rows = table.rows.map(({c}) => c.map(({v}) => v));

    console.log(header);
    console.log(rows);
  }
})
.fail((e) => console.log(e.status));
```

#### Sample script 3:

For example, when Sheets API v4 is used, the sample script is as follows. In this case, the API key is used. And it is required to publicly shared the Spreadsheet. Please be careful this.

```
var url = "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1l7VfPOI3TYtPuBZlZ-JMMiZW1OK6rzIBt8RFd6KmwbA/values/Sheet1?key=###"
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
  console.log(data.values);
});
```

#### References:

- [Query Language Reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage)
- [Response Format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/dev/implementing_data_source#response-format)
- [Method: spreadsheets.get of Sheets API v4](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)

Comment: All information is correct. in some projects, I am not using any API key. I am using only the "publish as a web" and convert into this "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1l7VfPOI3TYtPuBZlZJMMiZW1OK6rzIBt8RFd6KmwbA/1/public/values?alt=json" and show JSON data on my website. (1) v4 effect on "publish as a web" technic? (2) should I do anything. or this "publish as a web" technic is fine. Google nothing change in this?. @Tanaike

Comment: @Manish S Thank you for replying. I think that your endpoint of `https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/###/1/public/values?alt=json` is for Sheets API v3. And, Sheets API v3 will be deprecated in the near future. So you want to change the endpoint for retrieving the values from the web published Spreadsheet with `publish as a web`. I understood like this. If I misunderstood your question, please tell me.

Comment: @Manish S About your new 2 questions, A1: I think that `publish as a web` is not Sheets API v3. This is used for Query language and Google visualization. A2: Because `publish as a web` is not Sheets API v3, the endpoint in my answer like `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/###/gviz/tq` can be used after Sheets API v3 was deprecated. If I misunderstood your new 2 questions, I apologize.

Comment: Question: with the API v3 we were able to switch sheets by changing the `/1/` value in `https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/###/1/public/values?alt=json` to the index of the target sheet -- how does one achieve this with the sample solution 1 or 2 above?

Comment: @bomberjackets append "gid=###############" to the end of the query string like this: "/d/1l7VfPOI3TYtPuBZlZ-JMMiZW1OK6rzIBt8RFd6KmwbA/gviz/tq?tqx=out:json&gid=#########", where the gid number is the sheet number found in the google sheet url

Comment: yep!! is there anyway to get the sheet by index (ie. 0,1,2,3) if we don't have the gid?

Comment: @Tanaike In your Sample script 2, I'm finding that, in the case of a cell in a row that is empty, then I get the following error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'v' of 'object null' as it is null.` How would I modify your sample in order to get around this error?

Comment: @Tanaike I am using your Sample script 2, and when there is an empty cell in a row, it throws an error.

Comment: @lincolnberryiii Thank you for replying. Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your situation, I updated my sample script 2. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: @Tanaike Your update fixed my situation! Thank you very much!

Comment: @lincolnberryiii Thank you for replying. I'm glad the issue was resolved. Thank you, too.